# How to shorten a long running SQL Multiple-Join Statement

Tags: sql, jpa, derby

The following SQL statement is causing problems for me.

It runs regularly to sample data which is constantly being inserted into the tables. Approxiamately 10 records will be inserted across each of the tables each second in parallel to the execution of this query.

The tables are built using JPA but I am running the SQL as a native query in an attempt to optimize the query.

The problem :
I am trying to sample the data at a fixed rate (ideally once evey 5 or 10 minutes). But when the data set becomes large the execution time of the query passes the fixed rate and I do not get a steady sample.

Example :

```
Sample rate 10 seconds : query 740 ms
Sample rate 20 seconds : query 7.8 seconds
Sample rate 30 secodns : query 106 seconds **<- Unsustainable**
```

Each of the tables in the query has a composite primary key on `GWY` (Long), `SLV` (Integer) and `STMP` (java.sql.Timestamp). Also an index on each field independently `GWY`, `SLV`, `STMP`. There are non foreign keys.

The underlying database is embedded Derby.

Testing has shown that the query is above all very senstive to the number of tables in the join statement.

**The SQL statement :**

```
SELECT i1.GWY AS GWY, i1.SLV AS SLV, inv.SN AS SN, inv.NUMB AS NUMB, 
    MAX(cnt.TOT_COUNT) AS TOT_COUNT, AVG(inv.PWR_ACT) AS PWR_ACT, 
    MAX(sta.STAT) AS STAT, MIN(inv.CUR1) AS AC_CUR1_MN, MAX(inv.CUR1) AS 
    AC_CUR1_MX, AVG(inv.CUR1) AS AC_CUR1_AV, MIN(inv.CUR2) AS AC_CUR2_MN, 
    MAX(inv.CUR2) AS AC_CUR2_MX, AVG(inv.CUR2) AS AC_CUR2_AV, MIN(inv.CUR3) 
    AS AC_CUR3_MN, MAX(inv.CUR3) AS AC_CUR3_MX, AVG(inv.CUR3) AS AC_CUR3_AV, 
    MIN(inv.VOLT) AS AC_VOLT_MN, MAX(inv.VOLT) AS AC_VOLT_MX, AVG(inv.VOLT) 
    AS AC_VOLT_AV, MIN(idc.CUR1) AS DC_CUR1_MN, MAX(idc.CUR1) AS DC_CUR1_MX, 
    AVG(idc.CUR1) AS DC_CUR1_AV, MIN(idc.CUR2) AS DC_CUR2_MN, MAX(idc.CUR2)
    AS DC_CUR2_MX, AVG(idc.CUR2) AS DC_CUR2_AV, MIN(idc.CUR3) AS DC_CUR3_MN, 
    MAX(idc.CUR3) AS DC_CUR3_MX, AVG(idc.CUR3) AS DC_CUR3_AV, MIN(idc.CUR4) 
    AS DC_CUR4_MN, MAX(idc.CUR4) AS DC_CUR4_MX, AVG(idc.CUR4) AS DC_CUR4_AV, 
    MIN(idc.CUR5) AS DC_CUR5_MN, MAX(idc.CUR5) AS DC_CUR5_MX, AVG(idc.CUR5) 
    AS DC_CUR5_AV, MIN(idc.CUR6) AS DC_CUR6_MN, MAX(idc.CUR6) AS DC_CUR6_MX, 
    AVG(idc.CUR6) AS DC_CUR6_AV, MIN(idc.CUR7) AS DC_CUR7_MN, MAX(idc.CUR7) 
    AS DC_CUR7_MX, AVG(idc.CUR7) AS DC_CUR7_AV, MIN(idc.CUR8) AS DC_CUR8_MN, 
    MAX(idc.CUR8) AS DC_CUR8_MX, AVG(idc.CUR8) AS DC_CUR8_AV, MIN(idc.CUR9) 
    AS DC_CUR9_MN, MAX(idc.CUR9) AS DC_CUR9_MX, AVG(idc.CUR9) AS DC_CUR9_AV, 
    MIN(idc.CUR10) AS DC_CUR10_MN, MAX(idc.CUR10) AS DC_CUR10_MX,
    AVG(idc.CUR10) AS DC_CUR10_AV, MIN(idc.CUR11) AS DC_CUR11_MN, 
    MAX(idc.CUR11) AS DC_CUR11_MX, AVG(idc.CUR11) AS DC_CUR11_AV, 
    MIN(idc.CUR12) AS DC_CUR12_MN, MAX(idc.CUR12) AS DC_CUR12_MX, 
    AVG(idc.CUR12) AS DC_CUR12_AV, MIN(i1.VOLT) AS DC_VOLT1_MN, MAX(i1.VOLT) 
    AS DC_VOLT1_MX, AVG(i1.VOLT) AS DC_VOLT1_AV, MIN(i2.VOLT) AS 
    DC_VOLT2_MN, MAX(i2.VOLT) AS DC_VOLT2_MX, AVG(i2.VOLT) AS DC_VOLT2_AV, 
    MIN(i3.VOLT) AS DC_VOLT3_MN, MAX(i3.VOLT) AS DC_VOLT3_MX, AVG(i3.VOLT) 
    AS DC_VOLT3_AV, MIN(i1.MPPT) AS DC_MPPT1_MN, MAX(i1.MPPT) AS 
    DC_MPPT1_MX, AVG(i1.MPPT) AS DC_MPPT1_AV, MIN(i2.MPPT) AS DC_MPPT2_MN, 
    MAX(i2.MPPT) AS DC_MPPT2_MX, AVG(i2.MPPT) AS DC_MPPT2_AV, MIN(i3.MPPT) 
    AS DC_MPPT3_MN, MAX(i3.MPPT) AS DC_MPPT3_MX, AVG(i3.MPPT) AS DC_MPPT3_AV 

FROM INV1 i1 
LEFT JOIN INV2 i2 ON (i1.GWY = i2.GWY AND i1.SLV = i2.SLV)
LEFT JOIN INV3 i3 ON (i1.GWY = i3.GWY AND i1.SLV = i3.SLV)
LEFT JOIN IDC idc ON (i1.GWY = idc.GWY AND idc.SLV = i2.SLV)
LEFT JOIN INV_C inv ON (i1.GWY = inv.GWY AND i1.SLV = inv.SLV)
LEFT JOIN INV_S sta ON (i1.GWY = sta.GWY AND i1.SLV = sta.SLV)
LEFT JOIN I_COUNT cnt ON (i1.GWY = cnt.GWY AND i1.SLV = cnt.SLV) 

WHERE (i1.STMP BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2) 
    AND (i2.STMP BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2)
    AND (i3.STMP BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2) 
    AND (idc.STMP BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2) 
    AND (inv.STMP BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2) 
    AND (sta.STMP BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2) 
    AND (cnt.STMP BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2) 

GROUP BY i1.GWY, i1.SLV, inv.SN, inv.NUMB
```

Comment: You can use **Cross Apply or Outter Apply** in order to run the things concurrently.

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/PerformanceDiagnosisTips has some high level information that might help you get started.